# Documenting an Angular library

Tags: angular, documentation, documentation-generation, angular-library

I have been writing an Angular library and wondering if you use any tools, follow any conventions while documenting it.
Are there any common templates to create readme files, Gitbook or Confluence pages?

Comment: May be this will help:https://storybook.js.org/docs/angular/get-started/introduction/

Comment: The library I'm creating is not exactly a component library. It allows users to make video calls. Its public api includes only a module with a component. Component has an input for the configuration object and an output event. I'm not sure if it makes sense to use Storybook for my case.